# 'Line 2D' object has no property 'kind' -- Are pyplot.plot( ) and .plot( ) different?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm learning the pandas module on datacamp, and in a particular course, the instructor uses:

```
dog_pack.plot(x= "height_cm", y= "weight_kg", kind="scatter") 
plt.show()
```

to create a scatter plot. On my local PC, I try to do the same thing with the gapminder dataset, this works as intended:

```
# with the necessary imports (gapminder, matplotlib.pyplot, pandas)
gapminder.plot(x = "gdpPercap", y = "lifeExp", kind = "scatter")
```

But this throws an error:

```
# With the necessary imports
plt.plot(gapminder["gdpPercap"], gapminder["lifeExp"], kind = "scatter")

# This gives an error
```

And this works as intended:

```
plt.scatter(gapminder["gdpPercap"], gapminder["lifeExp"])
plt.show()
```

Are plt.plot( ) and .plot () (called on a dataframe) different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each function belongs to different library: `DataFrame.plot` is function of pandas, and `pyplot.plot` is a function of matplotlib.

Obviously, pandas' plot uses matplotlib to plot by default, as mentioned in [.plot documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). Even though, pandas developers decided on a bit different api, just to make it more convenient to plot a dataframe directly. So yes, they have different api - even so pandas is using pyplot in backend.

One example is `kind` attribute: it's an addition in pandas to easily plot, while in matplotlib the design is a bit different and you can't specify it.

Think that you are a developer of pandas: you have the way matplotlib plotting, but you want to make life easier (in your opinion) for your users. So for their opinions, designing one general `.plot` method with specifying a `kind` attribute is better for them and maybe easier for users.